# writing assembly code using function technique

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I am given a question in which I have to move an 8-bit number from memory location ABCDH:1200H into the memory location DCBAH:3456H. Following is my code:

```
   MOV [1200H], 6 
   MOV AL,[1200H]
    CALL FUNC
   HLT
   FUNC:

    MOV [3456H],AL
    RET
```

Is it correct?

Comment: You need to set the data segment register. Why are you moving a 6 out to `[1200]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> move an 8-bit number from memory location **ABCDH**:1200H into the memory location **DCBAH**:3456H.

Given that the source and destination reside in different memory segments your current solution will move the `AL` value to a location within the same segment where it was retrieved. Let's hope this was segment ABCDh to begin with!

```
mov ax, 0ABCDh
mov ds, ax
mov [1200h], 6       ;Initialize the source byte

mov al, [1200h]      ;Read source ABCDh:1200h
CALL FUNC
HLT
```

If you're going to do this transfer in a function then you should at least preserve the segment registers (that you would use).

```
; Input   AL
; Output  none
; Changes none
FUNC:
  push ds
  push dx
  mov  dx, 0DCBAh
  mov  ds, dx
  mov  [3456h], al  ;Write destination DCBAh:3456h
  pop  dx
  pop  ds
  ret
```